# cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE temp TABLE demo1(
    col_a int,
    col_b int DEFAULT (col_a)
);
```

PostgreSQL have generated columns, triggers. **But** why cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression.

since the manual [ddl-default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html) page mention:

> **The default value can be an expression**, which will be evaluated
> whenever the default value is inserted (not when the table is
> created). A common example is for a timestamp column to have a default
> of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, so that it gets set to the time of row
> insertion.

Obviously, column references is value expression.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-COLUMN-REFS

> A value expression is one of the following:
>
> ```
> * A constant or literal value
> ```

Comment: Well, a column reference is **not** "*a constant or literal value*". As for _why_ this isn't allowed: most probably because no one cared enough to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) states:

> `DEFAULT default_expr`
>
> The `DEFAULT` clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free expression (in particular, cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed). Subqueries are not allowed either. The data type of the default expression must match the data type of the column.

So the restriction is clearly documented.

But it is fairly easy to see that it would pose problems to allow a column reference in a `DEFAULT` expression: For one, the value specified in the `INSERT` statement could be overridden by `BEFORE INSERT` triggers. In that case, should the value *before* or *after* the trigger execution be used? Also, what if the `DEFAULT` for column `a` references column `b` and vice versa? There may be other difficulties that I didn't think of.